# Deactivated page is available after package replication

Tags: aem, aem-6

This is the scenario (CQ5.6). Let's say there is the following node /content/geometrixx/articles, with articles inside of it. In author instance I create a package as a backup of that node. Then I deactivate article1 inside of articles, if I try to access the page I get a 404 page, that is fine. However if I build the backup package again and then replicate it, the deactivated page (article1) is available, that is, I do not get the 404 but instead the article.

Is there a way to replicate a package while preserving deactivated pages? That is, how I avoid re-activation?

Comment: Solved using on/off time. But in the end, moved to curl commands and tree activation in order to avoid setting manually that on every deactivated page.

Answer (score 1):

Replicating package means that you are replicating every thing available in Package. Which means publish environment will have deactivated pages also. There are several ways to handle it, like:

1. Simplest way is to add a check in template (as first rule) to see if Env==publish && requested resource ==not activated, if so, return 404 page.
2. Another way is to create a script to delete all deactivated pages, and run this script on publish after page activation.
3. Add exclude filters in your package to exclude such pages.

I would recommend to use #1 as this is one time change and will be future proof.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the deactivated pages is not an option. Option 1 looks good, actually, another option is setting an on/off time in the page.

Answer (score 1):

should use treeactivation: http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/treeactivation.html, much safer (since you have 3 options: Only Modified, Only Activated and Ignore Deactivated)